# Win2D APIs fail randomly with error "Objects used together must be created from the same factory instance."

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, win2d

I am writing a UWP app with extensive use of Win2D APIs.

Sometimes, with no defined pattern, nor possibility to reproduce the behavior systematically, an un-caught exception of type System.Exception {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException} is raised by the framework, with no stack trace and only the following message:

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

and a slightly more useful description

```
Objects used together must be created from the same factory instance.
```

Since there is no stack trace, I am not able to understand what is the cause of such exception, nor the piece of code that produces it.

According to the description, I tried to use a single factory for every Win2D operation, and specifically, I collected into 3 public static variables the factories I use:

```
public static class Win2DUtils
{
    public static readonly Compositor Compositor = Window.Current.Compositor;
    public static readonly CanvasDevice CanvasDev = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
    public static readonly CompositionGraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice = CanvasComposition.CreateCompositionGraphicsDevice(Compositor, CanvasDev);
}
```

Even with this escamotage, I am still experiencing the issue.

I also tried in Visual Studio to flag all the possible Exception to stop the execution when they are raised, but if with this setting the Exception is completely un-caught, and can only be perceived thanks to the builtin exception handling of Visual Studio in Debug mode (the code in App.g.i.cs that is automatically added by the scaffolding of Visual Studio in every UWP project, something like:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

Is anybody aware of what could be the possible cause and at least how to catch the source of the exception?

Thank you very much

cghersi

Comment: Hi, You did not provide specific code at this time, but you can check your code based on the error message. According to the error message, you need to create your geometry from the same factory Win2D is using rather than creating a different factory from scratch.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT thanks, I added some code that explains what I tried, basically collect the factories I use to create the geometries into a single static variable. Any clue of what am I missing?

Comment: The problem may be on `CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice()`. In some cases, this exception occurs on the `CanvasRenderTarget` created by this device is called in the `CanvasControl_OnDraw` event. Please try to get device via `CreateResources`

Comment: Hi @RichardZhang-MSFT, thank you for the hint, that could be really useful! Could you please expand on how to use the CreateResources  API and link some documentation on that please?

Comment: Hi, at present, there are relatively few documents about the Win2d system. Here is a [description document](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/E_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_UI_Xaml_CanvasControl_CreateResources.htm) about the `CreateResources` event. You can search some related technical blogs to learn more.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help, since we are not related to some specific event of the CanvasControl, but we use Win2D in a general way. Is there any way to use the CreateResources API without starting from an event?

Comment: Hi, At present I haven't found the relevant instructions. If you want to use the event parameters of CreateResources, you must create the corresponding event processing code.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar error, but it crash only on some devices(all of them was with Intel HD Graphics). The reason was I forgot to remove CanvasDevice.DebugLevel = CanvasDebugLevel.Information;

```
        if (CanvasDevice != null)
        {
            CanvasDevice.DeviceLost -= CanvasDeviceOnDeviceLost;
        }

        CanvasDevice.DebugLevel = CanvasDebugLevel.Information;//Remove this on release. On some devices cause app crash        
        CanvasDevice = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
```

//error:Canvas.GetSharedDevice Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the issue (apparently) so I post for anybody else that hits the same problem.

In our code we are instantiating a `CanvasAnimatedControl` to draw some ink.

By default, the public parameter-less constructor of `CanvasAnimatedControl` sets the flag `UseSharedDevice` to false, which allows the `CanvasAnimatedControl` to create its own `CanvasDevice`.

Creating the canvas as:

```
aniCanvas = new CanvasAnimatedControl()
{
    UseSharedDevice = true
};
```

solved the problem and the exception doesn't show up anymore.